# Erasing a portion of the text on a webpage

Tags: javascript

So I'm working on a blackjack game and I have almost completed it except for the fact that if the user wants to play again, I do not have that as an option. I was thinking of putting a windows.confirm dialog box and when "ok" is selected the previous blackjack game that he just played will be erased. I was wondering how I would go about erasing that previous game or if there is a better way of doing it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Target the contained element, and remove it from the DOM.

Comment: We need to see a demo of your game, we don't even know if you're using jQuery or native js. Moreover, i'm pretty surprised you don't store in localStorage (or in a cookie, or serverSide) the current game of user, and maybe need to erase it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your element an Id, then hide it

for example,

```
<img id="mypic" src="xx.jpg" />

document.getElementById('mypic').style.display = 'none';
```